# How to connect single-phase power source to 3-phase motor

Tags: motor, ac, three-phase

My 3-phase, wye wound, 9-lead motor has:

- wires 1 & 7 connected to wire L1
- 2 & 8 connected to L2
- 3 & 9 connected to L3
- and 4, 5, 6 wired together.

I put a plug on one end of a cable, that is plugged into a 220 V dryer outlet. How are the three wires in the cable, connected to the motor wires?

Comment: A three-phase motor will not work from a single phase household 220 volt outlet.

Comment: Slight modification: A three phase motor will not work SMOOTHLY from a single phase 240 V outlet. It may spin, actually. Especially if you give it a little boost.

Comment: You have a three-phase motor that can be connected in wye or delta.  It cannot be powered by a single-phase power source.

Comment: There exists VFDs which accepts single phase input and output three phase. Probably simpler and cheaper to get a single phase motor though.

Answer (score 2):

It's not optimal but there is a way to run *small* 3-phase induction motors at reduced torque from a single phase supply.

It's called "Steinmetz connection" (Steinmetz being one of the developers of said motors). In short you can use a capacitor to create a 'fake' phase from the supply line. Search the web for formulas and details.